# React Native Fetch API - can't access json or body of response

Tags: android, django, react-native, fetch

Trying to call an API to my backend with Fetch, but I can't access the response body. There's a loot of different notation and syntax about this on the internet and I can't figure out how to do it properly.

I've tried response.json() and responseJson, and stringyfying both. I don't get what I want which is the actual body of the response. It's meant to have a key/token that I then save.

responseJson returns this: responseJson:

```
{"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}
```

This is my function:

```
export function LogIn(em, pass) {
    return (dispatch) => {

        console.log('LogIn called');
        dispatch(logInIsLoading(true));
        //from phone
        *fetch('http://192.168.1.18:8080/rest-auth/login/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            // 'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            'email': em,
            'password': pass,
          })
        }).then((response) => {
                console.log("response " + JSON.stringify(response));
                if (!response.ok) {
                    console.log("ERROR: " + response.statusText);
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                dispatch(logInIsLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => {
              responseJson = response.json();
              console.log("responseJson: " + JSON.stringify(response.json()));

              return responseJson
            })
            .then((responseJson) => {

              AsyncStorage.multiSet([['key', responseJson.key], ['loggedIn', true]], () => {
                    console.log(responseJson.key);
                    dispatch(isLoggedIn(true));
                    dispatch(getKey(responseJson.key));

                });


            })*
            .catch(() => dispatch(logInHasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

This is the response, but I can't get to the key in the body:

```
response {"type":"default","status":200,"ok":true,"headers":{"map":
{"allow":["POST, OPTIONS"],"set-cookie":
["csrftoken=DOMxD5IhNz5Vwm9a3niAR1tRyqBfNzUqnQMAEgk7AGwtwCgnRnZo9x0AMTM2IfK
q; expires=Fri, 22-Feb-2019 17:31:58 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/, 
sessionid=er3fujv8ji96t41n1n8dlzb3zz1itwuj; expires=Fri, 09-Mar-2018 
17:31:58 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/"],"content-type":
["application/json"],"content-length":["50"],"x-frame-options":
["SAMEORIGIN"],"vary":["Accept, Cookie"],"server":["WSGIServer/0.1 
Python/2.7.14"],"date":["Fri, 23 Feb 2018 17:31:58 
GMT"]}},"url":"http://192.168.1.18:8080/rest-auth/login/","_bodyInit":"
{\"key\":\"a9951fd6abff4fed35d9a8d1c275bf1212887513\"}","_bodyText":"
{\"key\":\"a9951fd6abff4fed35d9a8d1c275bf1212887513\"}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. response.json() return Promise
2. AsyncStorage.multiSet - return Promise. Second parameter of multiSet is Function that will be called with an array of any key-specific errors found

```js
export function LogIn(em, pass) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log('LogIn called');
        dispatch(logInIsLoading(true));
        fetch('http://192.168.1.18:8080/rest-auth/login/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            // 'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            'email': em,
            'password': pass,
          })
        }).then((response) => {
           if (!response.ok) {
              console.log("ERROR: " + response.statusText);
              throw Error(response.statusText);
           }
           dispatch(logInIsLoading(false));
           return response;
        })
        .then((response) => {
              return response.json()
        })
        .then((responseJson) => {
              console.log('responseJson', responseJson);
              return AsyncStorage.multiSet([['key', responseJson.key],['loggedIn', true]], () => {
                    dispatch(logInHasErrored(true));
              })
              .then(() => {    
                  dispatch(isLoggedIn(true));
                  dispatch(getKey(responseJson.key));
              })
        })
        .catch(() => dispatch(logInHasErrored(true)));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward with axios.
First install axios by doing `npm install --save axios`

Then inside your `Component` do this:

```
handleInput = async() => {
    const res = await axios.post('http://192.168.1.18:8080/rest-auth/login/', {
       email: this.state.email,
       password: this.state.password
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
}
```

Make sure you've stored email and password in `this.state.email` and `this.state.password` respectively and call `handleInput` when user presses the Submit button.
Don't forget to import axios `import axios from 'axios'`